# Delphi XE procedures instead of functions after WSDL importer execution

Tags: xml, web-services, delphi, soap, wsdl

I am trying to consume a NAV 2009 web service from Delphi XE6 (in XE5 is the same), I used "Import WSDL" from XE6 and the unit created exposes several SOAP methods as procedures instead of functions.

Here is a piece of code generated:

```
Ficha_Cliente_Port = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{928A4E8E-B9A4-4C91-9666-D4DFE550D3CD}']
    function  Read_(const No: string): Ficha_Cliente; stdcall;
    function  ReadByRecId(const recId: string): Ficha_Cliente; stdcall;
    function  ReadMultiple(const filter: Array_Of_Ficha_Cliente_Filter; const bookmarkKey: string; const setSize: Integer): Ficha_Cliente_List; stdcall;
    function  IsUpdated(const Key: string): Boolean; stdcall;
    function  GetRecIdFromKey(const Key: string): string; stdcall;
    procedure Create(const Ficha_Cliente: Ficha_Cliente); stdcall;
    procedure CreateMultiple(const Ficha_Cliente_List: Ficha_Cliente_List); stdcall;
    procedure Update(const Ficha_Cliente: Ficha_Cliente); stdcall;
    procedure UpdateMultiple(const Ficha_Cliente_List: Ficha_Cliente_List); stdcall;
    function  Delete(const Key: string): Boolean; stdcall;
end;
```

For example the method Create has to return an object of Ficha_Cliente type and there is no return value in this case due to this kind of implementation as procedure instead of function.

I can consume all the functions but no procedures.

I consumed this web service from php and c# without problem but I do not know the way to do it with delphi, I am new to Delphi.

*--------------------------------------------------
The method definitions in the WSDL are :

```
<operation name="Read"><input name="Read" message="tns:Read"/><output name="Read_Result" message="tns:Read_Result"/>
<operation name="Create"><input name="Create" message="tns:Create"/><output name="Create_Result" message="tns:Create_Result"/></operation>
```

The messages Read,Read_Result,Create and Create_Result are all of type Ficha_Cliente, It can see below

```
<message name="Create_Result"><part name="parameters" element="tns:Create_Result"/></message>

<xsd:element name="Create_Result">-<xsd:complexType>-<xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="Ficha_Cliente" type="tns:Ficha_Cliente" maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1"/></xsd:sequence></xsd:complexType></xsd:element>
```

That is, in my opinion the unit generated by Delphi with WSDL importer had to contain a function called Create whith an output of type Create_Result (that is of type Ficha_Cliente) but is missing.

If I try to execute in Delphi the command *(HTTPRIO1 as Ficha_Cliente_Port).Create(Ficha);* where Ficha is Ficha_Cliente typed, the project is compiled but I get an access violation error.

Comment: Um, no. `Create` creates a new client on the server, not a new instance of an object. You pass in a client object you've got, and it creates the record on the server. It's not a class constructor (which is not a function either). You're confusing the interface method `Create` with a class `constructor Create`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ken, I added some more information to my original post to clarify the problem. The cuestion is that I cannot execute the WSDL method called Create neither with nor without output parameter